# Xcode говорит что класс сущности под названием Car не был создан

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

Хотя я четко следовал инструкциям туториала, а именно создал сущность Car:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И дал ей класс Car:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Компилятор ругается и говорит что я использую незадекларированный тип Car
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Cmd+B нажимали?